# MS Power Query - generate a series of tables dynamically

Tags: excel, datatables, powerquery

I have a problem which I cannot find a way to solve - could you help me find a way to do that?

Problem general statement: given an input table with one "parent" column generate a series of tables consisting of all columns from the original table, each of those filtered for each of distinct values of the "parent" column

Example with simple data: I have an address table with the address, city, and country (represents the "parent"). I need to generate a series of queries, each of them being a separate table for each country

How do I do that? Thanks a lot!

I am stuck in this step where I managed to group data and have a table with distinct country names, with a table record next to them.
I can extract the data manually by duplicating the table, but I do not want to do that. I am looking for a dynamic solution

Comment: I'm curious - Why? What is the end goal? If the parent table had 101 distinct countries, you want to have 101 different tables? You cannot generate new queries dynamically in Power Query. Explain the end goal, as there may be an alternative to your needs.

Comment: Fair concern. My end goal is to automate visualization of ~50 org charts that start with different person (depending on what chart is aimed to show). Which is why I intended to transform data in this way and deliver it to the person who will be creating these org charts - each of them would relate to a separate table. This is why I created example with city and country, where hierarchical relationship is clear.

Comment: This is a terrible idea, but if you must, generate a single table with the variable, then use VBA to create all the queries from that dynamically

Comment: Or even just have the one table, and then use a filter/slicer for the desired sub-set.